# Pandas group by datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(np.arange(0,11), unit='h', origin='2018-08-01 00:00:00')

                 Date
0 2018-08-01 00:00:00
1 2018-08-01 01:00:00
2 2018-08-01 02:00:00
3 2018-08-01 03:00:00
4 2018-08-01 04:00:00
5 2018-08-01 05:00:00
6 2018-08-01 06:00:00
7 2018-08-01 07:00:00
8 2018-08-01 08:00:00
9 2018-08-01 09:00:00
10 2018-08-01 10:00:00
```

I want to create a new column 'Trip', which is an integer number which tells me which trip it is. All records within 4 hour of the start of the trip should be part of the trip. The result has to look like:

```
                 Date   Trip
0 2018-08-01 00:00:00   1
1 2018-08-01 01:00:00   1
2 2018-08-01 02:00:00   1
3 2018-08-01 03:00:00   1
4 2018-08-01 04:00:00   1
5 2018-08-01 05:00:00   2
6 2018-08-01 06:00:00   2
7 2018-08-01 07:00:00   2
8 2018-08-01 08:00:00   2
9 2018-08-01 09:00:00   2
10 2018-08-01 10:00:00  3
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda like this one :

```
df["Trip"] = df.apply(lambda x: (x["Date"].hour // 5) + 1, axis=1)
```

5 will be the number of hours you want to cover
The `+1` is here bbecause you want to start at Trip 1

With start hour different of 00:00:00

```
origin = df["Date"][0].hour
df["Trip"] = df.apply(lambda x: ((x["Date"].hour - origin) // 5) + 1, axis=1)
```

Other way to get it :

```
df["Trip"] = df.apply(lambda x: ((x["Date"].hour - origin) // 4.0) + 1, axis=1)
```

> Don't forget to convert to `int` if needed

Comment: The solution should look on the start of the first index. If the origin is '2018-08-01 03:00:00' it doesn't work because until index 8 it should count as 1 trip (all are within 5 hours)

Comment: If you apply that on `df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018,2018,2018,2018],
                   'month': [1, 1,1,1,1],
                   'day': [5, 5,5,5,5],
                   'hour': [1, 2,5,9,10],                   
                   'minute': [0, 15,30,40,50]})                                      

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df,format='%Y%m%d %H:%m')` it shows trip 1,1,3,5,5 instead of 1,1,2,3,3

Comment: After this I can do: `df['Trip'] = df.groupby('Trip').ngroup() +1 ` , I will look if this works in all cases

Comment: I got this : 1,1,1,2,2
Code:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018,2018,2018,2018], 'month': [1, 1,1,1,1], 'day': [5, 5,5,5,5], 'hour': [1, 2,5,9,10], 'minute': [0, 15,30,40,50]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df,format='%Y%m%d %H:%m')
origin = df["Date"][0].hour
df["Trip"] = df.apply(lambda x: ((x["Date"].hour - origin) // 5) + 1, axis=1)`

Comment: Or using `df["Trip"] = df.apply(lambda x: ((x["Date"].hour - origin) // 4.0) + 1, axis=1)` to make 1, 1, 2, 3, 3

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Do you know how to how to do `df["Trip"] = df.apply(lambda x: ((x["Date"].hour - origin) // 4.0) + 1, axis=1)` within index level (e.g. do this operation for all distinct indices?

Comment: I think with apply you can't, because the x in the lambda is a row...

Comment: Will it be possible to use apply function on a column df['ship'] with unique values?

Comment: Give more precision please

Comment: I mean, use your solution first on all rows where trip==1, then use your solution on all trip==2 , and then use your solution on trip==3.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Enjoy!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({})
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(np.arange(0,11), unit='h', origin='2018-08-01 00:00:00')

def get_cum_time(x):

    diff_time = x.Date - x.prev_date

    return diff_time / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

df['prev_date'] = df.Date.shift(1)

df['diff_time'] = df.apply(get_cum_time, axis=1)
df['cum_time'] = df.diff_time.cumsum()

df.cum_time.fillna(1.0, inplace=True)

def get_trip(x):
    return x // 4 + 1

df['Trip'] = df.cum_time.apply(get_trip)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                      Date           prev_date  diff_time  cum_time  Trip
0  2018-08-01 00:00:00                 NaT        NaN       1.0   1.0
1  2018-08-01 01:00:00 2018-08-01 00:00:00        1.0       1.0   1.0
2  2018-08-01 02:00:00 2018-08-01 01:00:00        1.0       2.0   1.0
3  2018-08-01 03:00:00 2018-08-01 02:00:00        1.0       3.0   1.0
4  2018-08-01 04:00:00 2018-08-01 03:00:00        1.0       4.0   2.0
5  2018-08-01 05:00:00 2018-08-01 04:00:00        1.0       5.0   2.0
6  2018-08-01 06:00:00 2018-08-01 05:00:00        1.0       6.0   2.0
7  2018-08-01 07:00:00 2018-08-01 06:00:00        1.0       7.0   2.0
8  2018-08-01 08:00:00 2018-08-01 07:00:00        1.0       8.0   3.0
9  2018-08-01 09:00:00 2018-08-01 08:00:00        1.0       9.0   3.0
10 2018-08-01 10:00:00 2018-08-01 09:00:00        1.0      10.0   3.0
```

Comment: Thanks. however, this assumes that data is always given for every 5 hours. If not,it wil show trip 1, 3,4, etc. In this case it worked but it is not generic